# Can I ask programming questions on other sites besides Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I am having a problem with HTML and CSS. Previously, I had asked one question on Programmers.SE related to Android. Now I am thinking of asking about my problem related to HTML and CSS on Webmasters.

Would it be the correct place to ask? I have a question ban on Stack Overflow. Does a question ban on Stack Overflow have anything to do with asking questions on other sites?

Comment: What is your HTML/CSS question?

Comment: Yes I have read almost all answers and working on lifting ban.. Just cant get it. The questions are beyond my scope still trying to answer as much I can.

Comment: Don't go asking off-topic questions on other sites just to circumvent your ban though. That will never go well. That being said, without knowing what question you want to ask, we can't tell you if it's appropriate for another site.

Comment: I am facing a problem I cant add background to an anchor in CSS so I need some assistance I dnt know which is the best place to ask.

Comment: Your CSS & HTML question would be off topic on Pro Webmasters, please read the [site's FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly, they explicitly mention that questions about HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding should be asked on Stack Overflow. Your question ban is unfortunate, but that doesn't mean you should ask off topic questions on other sites, that will only get you banned / suspended on those sites as well. Oh, and since we are talking about this, coding questions are off topic on Programmers as well.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bans are site-specific—algorithms find matches based on your history on a specific site.

You should look to improve your questions/answers on Stack Overflow, which is limited to programming questions. Code-based questions are usually preferred, but as long as you believe your question fits reasonably within the guidelines of the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), then you should be okay.

The other Stack Exchange sites that allow for programming questions and code review are [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but make sure to check out the FAQs on those sites to find out what questions are limited to there, as they differ greatly from Stack Overflow.

If your intention, by the way, is to get the question migrated to Stack Overflow from another site, that won't work. Please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) for more info on question bans.

Comment: Did you really have to point to Programmers? <sigh>

Comment: @YannisRizos: I can imagine the number of unfit questions you get per day, but keep in mind that I made it very clear that the sites differ greatly and that the FAQs never lie.

Comment: I'm a little on the edge as we are having a problem with questions that were rejected on SO and people trying to side step question bans, coincidentally I posted [this Meta question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/what-can-we-do-about-extremely-low-quality-questions-from-unregistered-users) only a few hours ago (it's focused on unregistered accounts, but the problem exists for registered ones as well, but with them I can simply suspend).

Comment: @YannisRizos: I'm well aware of that, but the most I can say is deal with it. All sites are having that problem and it's no easy thing for a new user (think of one whose first language isn't even English) to think that a site called "Programmers" wouldn't be fit for their incredibly specific questions about an error in programming. I wish I could change the way people work, but I can't. I just hope I made it sufficiently clear that Programmers is an entirely different creature.

Comment: `think of one whose first language isn't even English` That would be... me ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos: I know that, too, but I said "**new users** whose first language isn't even English." :P

Answer (score 1):

I guess at this point this answer is for other people who encounter this question online and are curious if there are other sites for coding Q&A. The answer is yes. There are a several. I am personally administrating [A New Developer / Programmer Friendly Q&A Site](https://newbstack.com) called newbstack.com. The focus is allow brand new developers to ask their questions without feeling intimidated by other more experienced developers. Your questions are moderated so you get help in phrasing your questions. We do ask you to put some effort in asking your questions but it is not a requirement and unless you are blatantly posting questions that are not coding related or are abusing the system in another way you will never get banned. Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the question was about other sites of the stackexchange network (but you likely know that). There have been some attempts to create more "compassionate" Q/A sites, but there is the high chance of a disparity of many, many people seeking (homework) help for things that they could solve if they read the ... manual, and people who would *like* to help, but then start to wonder why they should answer the same, poorly posed questions again and again. Good luck, though, maybe this time it's different...